# Oracle scheduler job return "Certificate validation failure"

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c, job-scheduling

I have developed a procedure on oracle database. It's works fine if I manually execute procedure using following scripts:

```
BEGIN TEST_JOBS.TEST_MAILS(null); END;
```

In order to run above job automatically I have created Oracle scheduler jobs which run periodically. But while scheduler execute it's return following error in my logs:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure
```

I have implemented my procedure scripts as following:

```
HTTP_REQ := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST("https://www.example-url.com", 'POST','HTTP/1.1');
utl_http.set_wallet('file:/u00/app/oracle/admin/CHTX12345/wallet','WalletPasswd123');  
utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml');
utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Length', length(env));
utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'SOAPAction', action);
utl_http.write_text(http_req, env);
http_resp := utl_http.get_response(http_req);


utl_http.read_text(http_resp, env);
utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
```

The oracle wallet has implemented by DBA, I don't know whether wallet setup has been correctly or not.

I am using oracle 12c.

Any ideas why am I getting `ORA-29273`?  Am I set up wallet correctly on procedure scripts?

Comment: Can you share complete procedure code (including create or replace ...) ?along with ‘execute ..’ statement ? Also, try procedure  with invokers rights 'AUTHID CURRENT_USER' if it helps... Hope the scheduler_job and procedure are in the same schema...

Comment: Validation error generally occurs when certificates are not implemented correctly to the wallet directory.

Comment: Since you are able to run it manually with no errors, I would expect the issue other than a wallet setup issue.

Comment: Hello guys, Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I have fixed this just changing order of these two lines :
utl_http.set_wallet('file:/u00/app/oracle/admin/CHTX12345/wallet','WalletPasswd123');                                                                              HTTP_REQ := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST("https://www.example-url.com", 'POST','HTTP/1.1');